# I've been given only 65 days tourist visa to Mexico but my return flight is 9 days later... should I rebook or risk being fined 40 dollars per day?

Tags: visas, overstaying, mexico

Stupidly, I have not filled out the form online which gives you automatic 6 months stay and was given only 65 days which I did not check and now I have to rebook a low cost return flight which will result in additional costs but maybe better than risking overstaying and paying 40 dollars per each day of overstaying which means 360 dollars?

Comment: Overstaying may actually have more implications, since in many visa applications you'll be asked if you've **ever** violated visa conditions **anywhere**

Answer (score 5):

It does depend on what kind of visa you were issued, but if you are a tourist on the standard FMM (Forma Migratoria Múltiple), and you were given less than the standard 180 days, and you need longer, you can go to an immigration office (INM) and ask to have it extended.  You will need all your documents - current visa, passport, reason for extension (and proof that you only need a small extension), and especially proof of ability to support yourself for those extra 9 days.

I have not had to do this, but I have heard that this is a pretty painless operation (as much as it ever is with Mexican bureaucracy).  It's not like the US or UK where they're immediately going to assume nefariousness.

Another option is to leave Mexico and come back in and get a new time on a new FMM.  But that requires being able to enter another country, and can be seen as suspicious (why are you wanting to spend more time here than we think is right?  Better to show the committed flight home to the immigration officers and explain why.)

As commented, it is best if you clear this up as soon as you can, rather than letting the visa expire.  Not only are there fines, but you may not be allowed back into Mexico; and you may find it more difficult to get a visa to the more suspicious countries, even years later.  Much better, is to get the visa extended.  Next best, rebook the flight.

Note that (barring emergencies) it is not possible to extend a tourist visa past 180 days.

A lot of this information is mentioned [at this commercial site](https://www.visasmexico.com/extend-mexican-visa-and-fmm/), I have not yet found the official government information.

Comment: Over the past several months it has become a lot more difficult to have the FMM extended, and I have heard of many people being denied extension.  INM are starting to enforce their tourism permit dates, are not automatically giving 180 days, and are not just automatically renewing them.  That said, they may extend by a week when shown evidence of flight bookings etc.

Comment: Would not be surprised, especially with "need extension (past 180) because covid".  But it's still the best first thing to try.  As you say, especially with "evidence of flight booking".